# How does one interact with a string drawn using UIStringDrawing/CoreText

Tags: iphone, drawing, nsstring, uitextview, core-text

I am attempting to work on an app that highlights certain key words. For this reason, I am looking at using either CoreText or UIStringDrawing to highlight these words (As in bold/underline/italicize/color) since UITextView doesn't seem to have these facilities (And I haven't had any luck with CATextLayer).

In either case I am able to successfully manipulate and draw the string. (I.E- I can find my important words in a string and apply the appropriate traits).

The problem I am having is that when text is drawn this way, it cannot be interacted with directly. Seeing as the user will be able to delete/add text to the text view in question, this is an important thing to have.

At the moment I have stuck my drawing routines into the drawRect: method of a UITextView subclass (Mostly just to see that I can do what I want). Does UITextView have a different method that can be overridden so that it uses my code to render its string? If not, how might I go about doing what I've described?

For an example of what I am talking about, look at how the Notes app finds and highlights phone numbers and addresses. I'm not looking for phone numbers or addresses, but it gets the point across.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of additional reading, it seems that you need to subclass/override a LOT of methods in order to create your own text view whose text you can draw. Apple's docs touch on it, but they don't go much into detail.